# What is the differnce between Corporate/Company level and Listing level Market cap

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, market-capitalization

Upon searching on google, I will end up getting types of MarketCap (Large, Mid, Small etc). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many companies have different classes of shares, but not all shares are listed on an exchange for trading (and some are not public at all too).

e.g. Alphabet (parent company of Google) has Class A shares (symbol: GOOGL) and Class C shares (symbol: GOOG) listed.  Class B shares are held by the founders and are not listed.

Other companies, such as BHP Billiton, have shares listed on different exchanges, each with their own capital structure (eg. LSE: BHP, ASX: BHP)

Corporate/Company level market cap includes these all these classes of shares across all exchanges and share classes.

The listing level market only gives the portion of the company's market cap attributed to that particular symbol/listing.

Comment: That perfectly answers my query.